# Alien abductee joins a galactic patrol where he is instructed by a bird-like alien

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

I remember a book in which the main protagonist is a human male and after witnessing alien activities he was forcibly whisked away. After being taken away he joins a type of galactic patrol type organization where one of his instructors/head instructor is described like an alien Big Bird.

Of the various scenes in the book, I remember the scene where the human man discovered the bird instructor literally "feeding the toilet". I also remember scenes with heavy drug use and scenes to make a sailor blush at least heavily implied if not described to some extent.

I read this book in middle school, so these scenes stick out the most in my memories. I have already checked and it is not a Steve Perry book. If I remember correctly, the one I read was paperback with a human male on the cover with a spaceship or space station behind him over a planet.

Could someone identify this book?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your description seems to be a pretty good match for the synopsis [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=EJ2BvOQUf0oC&lpg=PA279&dq=alien%20%22big%20bird%22%20novel&pg=PA279#v=onepage&q=alien%20%22big%20bird%22%20novel&f=false) of Rebecca Ore's *[Becoming Alien](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002QC07LM)* (1987). They mention a character named Tom who is involved in drug manufacture on Earth, and who then gets whisked away to join the Federation of Space Traveling Systems which includes many different alien species. One of these aliens is described as looking like Big Bird, and the reviewer comments that "the many details of their elimination processes [related to your 'feeding the toilet' comment?] and mating rituals are ultimately numbing." But the reviewer also says that "Despite these defects, *Becoming Alien* offers a leisurely trip through a fascinating world containing aliens that are sometimes as unforgettable as was Tweel in Stanley Weinbaum's '[A Martian Odyssey](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks06/0601191h.html).'"

The book was part of a [trilogy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00I0Z51OC), there were two sequels called *Being Alien* and *Human to Human*. Here are the harcover and paperback cover images (the paperback cover seems to have used an image of the alien from the movie *Enemy Mine*):

[image: harcover]

[image: paperback]